# How can I handle side effects within relations?

Tags: side-effects

I would like to handle side effects like generating fresh variables within a relation and not just within functions.

The "standard" way of handling side effects without direct language support in functional languages is via the use of applicative (monoidal) functors and monads. But this doesn't really work well with relations.

I would like to be able to write something like

```
Inductive entail: state prop -> state prop -> Prop :=
(* ... *)
| exists_intro P e:
  P e |- do x <- fresh ;
         do P' <- P x ;
         pure (colim x P')
where "P |- Q" := (entail P Q).
```

To generate a fresh variable for binding an existential quantifier.

But the above strikes me as very wrong.

From a theory POV the use of monads for handling side effects corresponds to the Kleisli category of the monad. A relational generalization ought to be the category of spans or the category of relations internal to the category of algebras of a monad. But this seems far too heavyweight and difficult for me.

Is there a simpler way to handle relational side effects?

IIRC a monad in Rel is a transitive reflexive relation but I don't think that really works for the type of side effects I want.

I'm well aware there are a wealth of ways other than monads to handle side effects. It might well be that a different approach would generalize better to relations. Still often stuff like substructural types requires language support or at least really really good EDSL facilities.

Comment: If a relation has a state then it may switch from being true to being false. Is that really what you expect for relations?

Comment: @Trebor https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2020/02/27/topos-theory-part-8/ Yes precisely for the case of time dependent sets. A proposition may be false now but become true later on. It's really hairy to try to mechanize this stuff though and TBH I don't really understand topos stuff.

Comment: Ahah generalized multicategories used Kliesli bicategories https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+multicategory#kleisli_bicategories not at all sure this would be comfy to mechanize. Definitely worth trying though.

Comment: Are you familiar with how logical frameworks deal with this sort of thing? For instance, [Twelf](http://twelf.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Abella](http://abella-prover.org) and [Beluga](http://complogic.cs.mcgill.ca/beluga/index.html)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer HOAS is really nice sometimes but requires special language support without ugly workarounds. Also variables aren't the only use for side effects in relations.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you use it, I was asking whether you were familiar with those techniques, for the purpose of getting closer to an answer. You phrased your question in a very general form, but you are only really looking at very special computational effects. Understanding logical frameworks helps study these special computational effects.

Comment: @AndrejBauer FWIW I'm also interested in what the "correct" notion of a multipredicate/multirelation ought to be. Should be useful in first order logic the same way arrows in multicategories are similar to terms with typing contexts.